# ssh command without tty hangs

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, tty

I'm trying to execute a simple ssh remote command from my local machine to an AWS instance, by running:

```
ssh -i /my/key.pem ec2-user@<myhost> 'ls -l'
```

When I do this, the command returns with exit code 255 and it leaves a process hanging on the ec2 instance `sshd: ec2-user [priv]`

If I run it with a tty

```
ssh -t -i /my/key.pem ec2-user@<myhost> 'ls -l'
```

It works. Even though `'ls -l` doesn't require user input, why does it still require a tty, and why does it leave that process hanging?

Comment: what do you have in your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent? Post verbose log of the connection `ssh -vvv ...`

Comment: no output on -vvv but i realized this is only happening when I'm on a VPN. not on VPN it works fine. not sure why that would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens in cases of X11 window forwarding - not sure why that would happen with ls, but setting DISPLAY has helped me in the past:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ssh -i ...
```